# Netlogo network extension: how to calculate mean path length for multiple link breeds?

Tags: social-networking, netlogo

I'm working on a program that compares the mean path length of multiple networks of turtles, but i'm having trouble identifying a way to calculate mean path length using netlogo's network extension for multiple link breeds. Right now, I'm using the following code (which doesn't include a way to reference which link-breeds to calculate the mean-path-length for):

```
to-report average-path-length

  report nw:mean-path-length

end
```

I've used the longer code in the small worlds model in the modeling library to calculate mean path length with multiple breeds in the past, but I'm hoping to find a way to do it with the network extension as it runs a lot faster. Please let me know if you've had any luck with this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way to tell the network extension which breeds of turtles and links to work with is to use the [`nw:set-context`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#set-context) primitive.

Here is a simple example comparing the mean path length of two different networks, built with two different turtle breeds:

```
extensions [ nw ]

breed [ mice mouse ]
breed [ frogs frog ]

to setup

  clear-all

  nw:generate-ring mice links 3
  nw:set-context mice links
  print nw:mean-path-length

  nw:generate-ring frogs links 5
  nw:set-context frogs links
  print nw:mean-path-length

end
```

This will print:

```
observer> setup
1
1.5
```

Here, both networks use regular (unbreeded) links, but you could also use different link breeds and specify which ones you want to work with using `nw:set-context`.